# MVC 6 asynchronous action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, dapper

So I've started my proof-of-concept for converting my nHibernate website to using Dapper.

My action method that I'm working appears to be working right now:

```
public IActionResult About()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

    var invoice = invoiceRepo.GetInvoiceAsync(19992031);
    var allInvoices = invoiceRepo.GetAllInvoicesAsync();

    var model = new Models.AboutModel
    {
        Invoice = invoice.Result,
        AllInvoices = allInvoices.Result
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

But then I realized/remembered, that in order for it to be asynchronous, I need to have `Task` on the action, like this:

```
public Task<IActionResult> About()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

    var invoice = invoiceRepo.GetInvoiceAsync(19992031);
    var allInvoices = invoiceRepo.GetAllInvoicesAsync();

    var model = new Models.AboutModel
    {
        Invoice = invoice.Result,
        AllInvoices = allInvoices.Result
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

But as soon as I do that, it tells me that I need to await something. In all of the examples I've seen, it just shows something like this:

```
var result = await repo.Get(param);
```

But I'm already doing the "awaiting" in my repos.

```
public async Task<Invoice> GetInvoiceAsync(int invoiceId)
{
    const string query = "select InvoiceId, Name [InvoiceName] from dbo.Invoice where InvoiceId = @invoiceId";

    using (var conn = GetConnection())
    {
        var dp = new DynamicParameters();
        dp.Add("@invoiceId", invoiceId);

        await conn.OpenAsync();
        var invoiceResult = await conn.QueryAsync<Invoice>(query, dp, null, 30, CommandType.Text);
        var invoice = invoiceResult.SingleOrDefault();

        return invoice;
    }
}

public async Task<List<Invoice>> GetAllInvoicesAsync()
{
    const string query = "select InvoiceId, Name [InvoiceName] from dbo.Invoice where SalesPeriodId >= 17";

    using (var conn = GetConnection())
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        var invoiceResult = await conn.QueryAsync<Invoice>(query, null, null, 30, CommandType.Text);
        var invoices = invoiceResult.Take(1000).ToList();

        return invoices;
    }
}
```

So the whole point in me switching to asynchronous is to be able to do both of my calls asynchronously, then merge the results together when returning.

How do I change my controller action to do this asynchronously, while having the `Task<IActionResult>`? Like this:

```
public Task<IActionResult>About() {}
```

Update: is this correct then?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> About()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

    var invoice = invoiceRepo.GetInvoiceAsync(19992031);
    var allInvoices = invoiceRepo.GetAllInvoicesAsync();

    var model = new Models.AboutModel
    {
        Invoice = await invoice,
        AllInvoices = await allInvoices
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Will this do both repo calls asynchronously (in parallel)?

Comment: You almost certainly want `var model = new Models.AboutModel
    {
        Invoice = await invoice,
        AllInvoices = await allInvoices
    };`

Comment: @ganders: Just a nitpick - it would probably be better to have `var invoice = await invoiceRepo.GetInvoiceAsync(19992031);` and similar for `allInvoices`, because that way the variable called `invoice` actually refers to an invoice, and not to a task that will eventually result in an invoice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await in your controller too. Rule of thumb: Never say `.Result`, instead say `await`.

You should also declare your action method as `public async` as well.

Update: That would be the correct way to asynchronously call your repositories. The database calls should happen in parallel because both tasks are started before anything is awaited. You can always see this yourself by putting debug logging at the start and end of your DB methods and seeing that you get "start 1 start 2 end 1 end 2" or something similar instead of "start 1 end 1 start 2 end 2" if your queries are reasonably slow.